# rhythmbox-metadata uses 100% cpu

Tags: rhythmbox, cpu

Everytime I start rhythm box the process rhythmbox-metadata starts up and uses 100% cpu on one core, causing the computer to heat up and the fans to start rotating hard.  I have an external drive with about 450GB of music. rhythmbox-metadata will remain active at 100% cpu for an hour and then stop consuming cpu. This happens everytime I open rhythm box even if nothing changed in the music folder.

How can I stop this behaviour ?

Comment: ok, it seems either you disable the watch feature or you get the cpu hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to deselect "Watch my library for new files" in Edit/Preferences to prevent rythmbox from using 100% cpu.